# Titanium.App.addEventListener not fired, never

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

app.js

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    layout: 'vertical',

});

win1.open();

Titanium.App.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

If I tap/click on the screen, the click event doesn't fire! Do you know why?
All my code is that above on app.js

**EDIT**

- If I would listen for a "swipe" event, how I would to do?
- Why I don't see errors or warning in my debug console for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "click" event is fired on the object that is clicked, namely, win1. So is "swipe". Please read [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-swipe) to learn what events are available.

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    layout: 'vertical'
});
win1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('clicked');
});
win1.addEventListener('swipe', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('swiped');
});
win1.open();
```

Your code is valid, so no errors or warnings are displayed. But it does not do what you expect. Please read [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.App) on the standard events that fire on Titanium.App, and on the custom events that you can fire on Titanium.App. Also read [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-swipe) on Titanium.UI.View to understand what standard events are fired.

Comment: Ok, actually I would "listener" for a "swipe" event. It's the same?

Comment: You should ask the documentation. I can answer, but then you'd never know how to know for certain, yourself!

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-swipe